# prove that $\sum_{cyc}\frac{{a^2}{b}}{c}\ge a^2+b^2+c^2$

Tags: inequality, summation, factoring, sum-of-squares-method

prove $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{{a^2}{b}}{c}\ge a^2+b^2+c^2$$ where $a,b,c>0$ and $a\ge b\ge c$

My try it seemed qite simple but i couldnt  apply the rearrangement inequality directly.  so  i tried manipulating the inequality.

the inequality can be written as $$a^2(b-c)+b^2(c-a)+c^2(a-b)\ge 0$$ .It seemed like 'schurs' inequality could be uused but i couldn't procceed.Also i tried using the  weighted a-m g-m method. Could anyone give me a hint (i want to solve the problem myself).

source: Excursion in mathematics(Modak)

Comment: Does $a^2(b-c)+b^2(c-a)+c^2(a-b)$ factorise?

Comment: (Not related to question) Good luck for JEE advanced, although if protesters have their way, you could be looking at a long wait. I gave it the first year they changed format, but now things must be very different! (If you wish to know more, call me to chat).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon thank you! i have just in 12 th so i guess things would have cleared up a bit by next april.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, I hope JEE Advanced doesn't get postponed!!

Comment: @VishnuKadiri With you on this one.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon you gave JEE Advanced in 2006? What is your rank? I would like to know more. I gave JEE mains in January and have got a fairly good score. Also, I see you are a fan of Mentalist. Pardon me for chatting in the chat.

Comment: Also, I would like to which method @Quantum used to rewrite the inequality in that manner.

Comment: @VishnuKadiri I gave advanced in 2013, without any coaching center's help. I did not do too bad, in top 10000. JEE mains score was 200, I think. Also, I love Lisbon, she's the best

Comment: @TeresaLisbon if it was 2013 that would be quite difficult as the paper pattern changed from subjective to objective

Comment: @Quantum Yes, you are correct. Look, I was not actually too keen on that. I gave the KVPY with more eagerness, and did well there! But now everything is an industry, it wasn't so(at least as much) back then. I do sympathise with you and Vishnu here. Just dug it out, I got 145/360 and rank 9741.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon what was your rank  in KVPY. I wrote that in 11th and bungled up because i ddnt study 12th portions in 11th

Comment: @Quantum I wrote it in $11$th, and bungled up. Then I wrote it in $12$th : rank $515$, but "only interview" rank was in top $10$, I've heard (but never confirmed : one guy told me this). That was pretty good, again given that I did no coaching of any kind, but just past papers, past papers, past papers. (Having  a picture of Lisbon on your laptop helps!)

Comment: @Quantum what is your mains percentile?

Comment: @VishnuKadiri i am yet to write it. (i have just started 12) what about yours

Comment: @Quantum Around 99.8 percentile.

Comment: @VishnuKadiri that is quite good. when you are free you can call me to chat.Would like to know more about your preperation strategies.good luck for jee adv.!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first step is wrong:

We need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^2-a^3bc)\geq0$$ and it indeed gives a proof:
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^3b^2-2a^3bc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^2+a^3c^2-2a^3bc)\geq\sum_{cyc}(a^3c^2-a^3b^2)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}a^3(b-c)^2\geq(ab+ac+bc)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a),$$ which is obvious.

We can get $$\sum_{cyc}(a^3c^2-a^3b^2)=(ab+ac+bc)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$$ by the following way.

For $a=b$, $a=c$ and  $b=c$ we obtain identity, which says that $$\sum_{cyc}(a^3c^2-a^3b^2)=P(a,b,c)(a-b)(b-c)(c-a),$$ where $P$ is a cyclic homogeneous polynomial of second degree.

Id est $$P(a,b,c)=\sum_{cyc}(ka^2+mab).$$
Now, $k=0$ because, otherwise there is a problem on $\infty$.

Also, let $c=0$.

We obtain: $$b^3a^2-a^3b^2=mab(a-b)b(-a)$$ or
$$a^2b^2(b-a)=ma^2b^2(b-a),$$ which gives $m=1$.

Factoring of some Schur's polynomials:
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2b-a^2c)=(a-b)(a-c)(b-c),$$
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3b-a^3c)=(a+b+c)(a-b)(a-c)(b-c),$$
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b-a^4c)=(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+ac+bc)(a-b)(a-c)(b-c),$$
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3b^2-a^3c^2)=(ab+ac+bc)(a-b)(a-c)(b-c),$$
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^5b-a^5c)=$$
$$=(a^3+b^3+c^3+a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b+abc)(a-b)(a-c)(b-c),$$
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b^2-a^4c^2)=(a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b+2abc)(a-b)(a-c)(b-c),...$$

Comment: Nice realization.

Comment: one question : how did you factorise the RHS as ($ab+bc+ca)(a-b).(..) $  did you know it  before or does it take time to factorise it

Comment: @Quantum Yes, of course. I knew it before. I got this factorization, when was a student of a school. This polynomial named as the Schur's polynomial. It's so useful that if you want I can write by memory factoring of any Schur's polynomials of sixth degree and less.

Comment: interesting,  is there a link that shows such factorisations. i will be very grateful if you can provide that . i tried researching it a bit but most of them are too complicated and i dont see  any similarity btw the ones you have used

Comment: thank you so much! i am going to memorize  them

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Thank you for giving such helpful results. Now I can understand the first step for this problem https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2006_IMO_Problems/Problem_3

Answer (score 2):

I will continue from the latest inequality presented by @Quantum. $\ {a}^{2}(b-c)+{b}^{2}(c-a)+{c}^{2}(a-b)={a}^{2}(b-c)+{b}^{2}(c-b+b-a)+{c}^{2}(a-b)$
$$\ ={a}^{2}(b-c)-{b}^{2}(b-c)-{b}^{2}(a-b)+{c}^{2}(a-b)=({a}^{2}-{b}^{2})(b-c)-({b}^{2}-{c}^{2})(a-b)$$
$$\ =(a-b)(b-c)(a+b-(b+c))=(a-b)(b-c)(a-c)\geq0$$

I hope it is simple.

Comment: This is not correct because quantum's representation is not correct

Comment: Yes i  get my mistake.  my simplification is wrong and so the whole proof is  gone!

Comment: Hahaha, I should have simplified the original problem. No worries!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to say that for $b=a$ and $b=c$ with $a\ge b\ge c$ we have equality.
Now differentiate

$$a^2b+b^2c+c^2a-a^2c-b^2a-c^2b$$ as a polynomial in $b$ it gives $(a-c)(a+c-2b)$ so it should be clear the behaviour as $b\in [c,a]$

Comment: i understand the intuition behind and due to symmetry a=b=c is an extreme value however i am looking for  a solid proof that does not take that assumption.

Comment: Your inequality in $b$ for $a$, $c$ fixed as you expand it takes $0$ for $b=c$ and $b=a$ and positive otherwise you know the derivative and the function variation...